# How to change the url for signin page in next-auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

In Next.js project I've implemented authentication with Next-Auth.

In **index.js** (as the Next-Auth documentation explains) I return a *User* only if there is a *session*

```
export default function Home({characters}) {
    const {data: session} = useSession()

    return (
        <>
            <Meta
                description="Generated by create next app"
                title={!session ? "Home - Login" : `Home - ${session.user.name}`}
            />
            {session ? <User session={session} /> : <Guest/>}

        </>
    )
}
```

In the *Guest* component I have a Sign In button, and the *onClick* event points to the **signIn** method from *"next-auth/react"*

```
function Guest() {
    return <Layout className="flex flex-col h-screen">
        <div className="font-extrabold mb-4 text-3xl">GUEST USER</div>

        <Button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign In</Button>

    </Layout>
}
```

as soon as I click that button I'm redirected to this `pages/auth/signin.js` page.

This is the page where I can login through *EmailProvider* or *GoogleProvider*

```
import { getCsrfToken, getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import { Meta, Layout, Card, InputGroup, Button } from "../../components/ui";

export default function SignIn({ csrfToken, providers }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Meta title="Login"/>
            <Card>
                <form method="post" action="/api/auth/signin/email">
                    <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" defaultValue={csrfToken} />
                    <InputGroup
                        type="email"
                        htmlFor="email"
                        label="Email"
                        name="email"
                    />
                    <Button type="submit">Sign in with Email</Button>
                </form>
                {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => {
                    if(provider.name === "Email") {
                        return
                    }
                    return (<div className="mt-3" key={provider.name}>
                        <Button onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)}>
                            Sign in with {provider.name}
                        </Button>
                    </div>)
                })}
            </Card>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken(context)
    const providers = await getProviders()
    return {
        props: { csrfToken, providers },
    }
}
```

When I'm in this page the url is `http://localhost:3000/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000`

***I wanna know if it's possible to change that url to a more polite one like `http://localhost:3000/login` or something like this.***

This page is already a custom login page as you can see in my `[...nextauth].js`

```
pages: {
  signIn: '/auth/signin',
},
```

any suggestions? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should work. Lets say you put this in your `[...nextauth].js` options

```
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  }
```

The signIn button will now redirect to `/login`.

Then you just have to put your login page under pages: `pages/login.js`.

Comment: I've just tried, but `?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000` is still present in the URL

Comment: Oh if you don't want the callbackUrl query param then you will have to redirect to your login page with you own logic (not using the built in signIn button). 
So in your Guest component you can use a link with `href='/login'` instead of this:
`<Button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign In</Button>`

Comment: Of course, the solution was so simple! Thanks man! A final question: you think it's secure and a good practice using only EmailProvider and GoogleProvider?
I prefer not to use CredentialsProvider, even for the complexity of the implementation of it

Comment: Yes definitely if you don't have existing users/accounts it's the way to go! Now you just have provider access tokens it's alot less of a risk than passwords!